# Memory Leak in Crashlytics Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, leakcanary

I am using Crashlytics 2.6.5 in my app. [Leak Canary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) always report a memory leak in `CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler`. Does anyone face this before? Please refer the attached image for more info

[image]